# Change Grails 3 URL to HTTPS

Tags: grails, https

I have setup SSL within my Grails 3.3 application as follows and it works appropriately.

```
environments:
    development:
        server:
                port: 8443
                ssl:
                  enabled: true
                  key-store: './localkeystore'
                  key-store-password: 'localonly'
                  key-password: 'localonly'
```

However, I have to manually change the URL to https in the browser. I am using IntelliJ IDEA to deploy locally with the Gradle bootRun command. The deployment log shows the URL upon deployment as unsecure. How can I change this URL to https?

> Grails application running at http://localhost:8080/application in
>   environment: development

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running the application with the Gradle bootRun command:

Open `build.gradle` file and add following configuration there:

```
bootRun {
    systemProperty 'server.port', '8443'
    systemProperty 'server.ssl.enabled', 'true'
    systemProperty 'server.ssl.key-store', './localkeystore'
    systemProperty 'server.ssl.key-store-password', 'localonly'
    systemProperty 'server.ssl.key-password', 'localonly'   
}
```

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Edit the run configuration for your grails application and add `-https` option to the command line.
It would be : `grails run-app -https ...`

Comment: I am running the application with the Gradle bootRun command not the grails run-app.